# Unwanted space in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a 2 column layout for getting a feel for HTML again.

I want to avoid using floats because I want to keep the natural document flow. Every other question on Stack Overflow I browsed through incorporate floats or worse tables. I tried layouting it with `flex` as well but I couldn't figure out how to make both the columns stay the same size on the other pages with different amounts of content in the first column.

Here's what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wykenakw/

I figured out through trial and error that I can use a negative margin to line up the sidebar to the main content but it feels awkward, quirky and hacky. I inspected every element inside my columns but I couldn't find any potential child elements with margins that could cause this 4px gap. It's driving me nuts.

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I see a lot of words there, but none of them seem to explain where the "unwanted space" resides.

Comment: Off-topic: Such a clean, simple design should really incorporate responsive behavior, or at least fluid column widths. Your 960px template was outdated 3 years ago considering that roughly half of all web consumption is now done on mobile.

Comment: Consider using a framework like bootstrap, where achieving various column layouts take seconds.

Comment: Also, you're using a bunch of vendor prefixes that aren't necessary anymore. See http://caniuse.com/#search=transition.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is ideal because it will essentially cut out the "white space" for you. You can try and use: `white-space-collapse:discard` on parent elements (in this case `#wrapper`), but I rarely have success using it.

White space is just a "natural" occurrence created by the browser rendering. In order to avoid this (without using float), you need to simply remove the white space between your elements. This isn't ideal because of the flow and indentation of the elements, but without using float it's what has to be done.

Additionally, in my opinion there is nothing wrong with using `float` as a "natural document flow". You can always `clear` the elements.

So instead of:

```
</main>

<aside id="col_2">
```

You'd have:

```
    </main><aside id="col_2">
```

Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/wykenakw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<main>` into a `<div>` or use css to turn it into a block element:

```
main {
    display: block;
}
```

As mentioned in the other answer actual spaces between the two elements is causing the unwanted whitespace. However spaces between two block elements is always ignored.